# How do I make the default content View filterable by multiple content types?

Tags: views, 9

Below is a clip from the content list admin page in Drupal 9, showing the Content type field drop-list, allowing admin users to filter the content list by content type.

Is there any way to alter this form to allow the list to be filtered by more than one content type at once? ie turn the content type drop-list into a multi-select field or checkboxes?

[image: Clip from the content list admin page, showing the Content type field drop list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This admin page is a Drupal View. Go to /admin/structure/views/view/content. Under **Filter Criteria**, click **Content: Content type (exposed)** and check the box that says **Allow multiple selections**. Save the setting then save the View.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Accepted.